# FluxCD :: Azure :: Ephemeral environments

Tags: azure-devops, fluxcd

I'm using fluxcd in azure to manage gitops for a java team deploying to kubernetes. I want to be able to test branches and pull requests before merging.

Although I've not implemented it yet, I'm thinking about using flux's multi-tenancy support for this, creating a tenant per branch. I can respond to a git code event by triggering a pipeline that creates a new namespace and a new tenant with a deployment (and maybe test cycle), driven by changes to that branch.

I've checked, and there are suitable events in the azure devops service hooks, and if I can get it installed I think I can use the flux cli to run a namespace pipeline at cluster level and create the new resources.

My question: has anyone else tried this?